# How to replace row delimiter character with another character?

Tags: xml, azure, dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory, fetchxml

Here the line in which i am fetching the "comment" attribute from dynamics CRM using FetchXml

attribute name="comment"

If in a comment attribute the "/r/n" is coming in between them and if i want to replace that with some another special character, how can I replace "/r/n" with another, in FetchXml query?

Comment: Did my answer help you with the issue? If so, please mark it as accepted. If not, let me know and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't replace `r/n/` as part of the FetchXml query (This would actually mean doing an update on the comment on the database). You first retrieve the records, and then do the replacing.

For example, say you've got the comment field on the Account entity, then (on server side):

```
string fetch = @"  
   <fetch version='1.0' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>  
     <entity name='account'>   
        <attribute name='comment'/>   
     </entity>   
   </fetch> ";   

EntityCollection result = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetch));
foreach (var account in result.Entities)
{
   // replace \r\n with a comma
   string comment = account.GetAttributeValue<string>("comment"); 
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comment))
   {
       var lines = comment.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
       Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", lines)); 
   } 
}
```